# Observable.create results in groovy.lang.MissingMethodException when running in verticle deployed via container.deployVerticle

Tags: groovy, vert.x, rx-java

```
import rx.*
class Foo extends Verticle {
    def start() {

        // This works:  prints 1
        Observable.create({ s -> s.onNext(1); s.onCompleted()}).subscribe({println it});

        container.deployVerticle("groovy:path.to.Bar")
    }
}

class Bar extends Verticle {
    def start() {
         // This fails
         Observable.create({ s -> s.onNext(1); s.onCompleted()}).subscribe({println it});
    }
}
```

Exception in Groovy verticle  (Bar.start)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static rx.Observable.create() is applicable

Class loader problem?  Not sure.  [Vertx documentation suggests](http://vertx.io/mods_manual.html#module-classloaders) container.deployVerticle verticles will use the parent class loader.

Maven:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.netflix.rxjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxjava-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.17.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.netflix.rxjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxjava-groovy</artifactId>
      <version>0.17.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Vert.x version: 2.1M5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the available API. In the RxJava wiki there are a lot of functions described but some of them are not implemented in the language adaptors. I am sure this is the case in Scala, but this is probably the same in Groovy. Sometimes methods even have different names like "switchOnNext" in Java and "switch" in Scala.